# Grep complete name including dot in the word

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

In a `ksh` shell script I am using a `grep` command to get a specific word as shown below.

```
$ cat file.txt
abc xyzdef.123 def.jkl mnopqrst

$ grep -o "\wdef\w" file.txt
xyzdef
def
```

I want output to be `xyzdef.123` and `def.jkl`

It is not fetching the value after `.` Is there any other way to `grep` this word also I don't know the exact word to `grep` only I know a pattern. I am working on `ksh` shell.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you just want the string `def` and all non-whitespace characters around it. If so, you can use:

```
$ grep -Eo '\S*def\S*' file.txt 
xyzdef.123
def.jkl
```

The `\S` means non-whitespace and is supported by GNU `grep` with either the `-E` or `-P` flags.

Comment: Actually this seems to be recognized in GNU grep by default (i.e., without options like `-E` or `-P`).

Comment: @Scott huh, so it is. Even busybox grep seems to grok `\S`. Still, it isn't in the BRE so better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Using `grep -o` and POSIX character classes:

```
grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*def[^[:blank:]]*' file.txt
```

This is essentially what [terdon suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/521687/116858), albeit using slightly different syntax (and no `-E`).  This would match the string `def` and any non-blank characters on either side of that string (a non-blank character is a character that is not a space or a tab).

Alternatively,

```
tr '[:blank:]' '\n' <file | grep -F 'def'
```

This just breaks the line down into multiple lines, one line per blank-separated word (where a "blank" is a tab or a space character). Then it applies a plain string match with `grep -F` on the generated lines to find the ones that you're interested in.

---

Your pattern, `\wdef\w`, which with GNU `grep`, if using POSIX character class names, is the same as `[[:alnum:]_]def[[:alnum:]_]`, requires that the string `def` is flanked by a alphanumeric character or underscore on either side.  A dot is neither an alphanumeric character nor an underscore.

The pattern also would not match `def` if it occurs at the very start or end of a line.

Comment: `tr ' \t' '\n'`  would be more bullet-resistant.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, modified it in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

With the attempt you have, you can't match the whole word to be returned. The `-o` flag of `grep` only returns the matched regex portion defined. Also `\w` is not a POSIX defined extension for `grep` and might be available only in the GNU versions which support the PCRE syntax. On which you could do

```
grep -oP '(\w*)def[.](\w*)'
```

The `-P` flag turns on the PCRE regex mode in GNU `grep` and the `-o` flag returns the whole word matched the regex defined. The regex is translated as match zero or more number of alphanumeric characters followed by `def` and a literal `.` ( enclosed in a bracket expression ) and followed by zero or more number of alphanumeric characters.

Using POSIX character classes for alphanumeric characters would be doing below. But remember the flag `-o` is still a GNU extension

```
grep -o '\([[:alnum:]]*\)def[.]\([[:alnum:]]*\)'
```

Comment: Instead of `[.]`, better use `\.` for a literal dot

Comment: The `-E` flag for `grep`, at least on GNU `grep`, also supports `\w`.

Comment: The only thing with this is that it requires the dot to be there, so it would not match the lone word `def`.  However, I'm uncertain this is an issue for the questioner.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Agreed, OP says _including_ the `.` in the word, I assumed in the positive cases `def` is always present with the `.`

Comment: Yes, including the dot in the word _in the data_, not in the query. But it may not be an issue if the dot is always there (but see the first/last word in the data).

Comment: Yes it is not necessary that we always have a dot in the word.

Comment: @Philippos:  Why do you say **``\.``** is better than **``[.]``**?

Comment: it is possible to achieve same by awk command ??

Comment: @Scott Three things: 1) There is a given way to express a literal dot, so why use a clumsy way to achieve the same? 2) Efficiency: depending on the implementation it will take more time to loop to a one-element-list than to directly use that element. 3) Main reason: readability. When a `regexp` is growing more complicated, it is important to help the reader understand it on the first glance.